# Python KeyError : 0, can you help me find the error?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I have a keyError 0 in my python code.

I dont really understand what in means in my case I read a lot about it but I cant find my error on my own
can somebody help me find it and maybe explain it to me ?

regards,

```
# use a function to pull all info from website
def getdata(stock):
# company quote group of items
    company_quote = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/{stock}")
    company_quote = company_quote.json()
    share_price = float("{0:.2f}".format(company_quote[0]['price']))

# balance sheet 
    BS = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/balance-sheet-statement/{stock}?period=quarter")
    BS = BS.json()

# total debt
    debt = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(BS['financials'][0]['Total debt'])/10**9))

# total cash
    cash = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(BS['financials'][0]['Cash and short-term investments'])/10**9))

# income statement group of item
    IS = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/income-statement/{stock}?period=quarter")
    IS = IS.json()

# most recent quarterly revenue 
    qRev = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(IS['financials'][0]['Revenue'])/10**9))

# company profile group of items
    company_info = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile/{stock}")
    company_info = company_info.json()

# CEO
    ceo = company_info['profile']['ceo']

    return (share_price, cash, debt, qRev, ceo)

tickers = ('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'MVIS')
data = map(getdata, tickers)

# create the dataframe with pandas to store all of the info 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Total Cash', 'Total Debt', 'Q3 2019 Revenue', 'CEO'], index = tickers)
print(df)

# writing to excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('example.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Statistics')
writer.save()
```

Comment: You haven't actually added any code for us to see, only written "Here is my script"..

Comment: My bad went to fast when I posted it, now its added

Answer (score 2):

I just executed the code you pasted and seems the issue is you are not using correctly the API, seems it is missing an API KEY, from your code I get this:

```sh
{'Error Message': 'Invalid API KEY. Please retry or visit our documentation to create one FREE https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in getdata
KeyError: 0
```

So, take a look to the API and send the correct values (Probably it is missing a header or so on)